# Occasion 503 error from google login callback, Django

Tags: django, google-api, django-allauth, google-signin, http-status-code-500

Somehow I receive 503 error report related to Google Social Login. Does it mean Google occasionally broke down? I have a hard time to reproduce it on either development server or production server.

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/google/login/callback/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py", line 55, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py", line 116, in dispatch
    response=access_token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/views.py", line 20, in complete_login
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=xxxx&alt=json
```

Environment:

- Django==1.8.8
- django-allauth==0.24.1

Comment: The general rule of HTTP status codes: 4xx = you failed, 5xx = they failed.

Comment: @KlausD. It makes sense, but I find it very hard to believe it is them who fail. It happens in a very low traffic service, about couple times a week.